# Avoid script file reloading JSP in Spring

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp

I am reloading a JSP page in every 10 seconds and I realised that everytime it reloads the script files and that increase the size and finally my page crashes.

This is my jsp and script to reload-

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<%
//JSP code
long ts = (new Date()).getTime(); //Used to prevent JS/CSS caching
%>
<title>Login Success</title>
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-united.css?<%=ts %>" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="assets/css/customtable.css?<%=ts %>" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js?<%=ts %>"></script>  
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js?<%=ts %>">
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="buntha">


<div class="navbar navbar-default">

    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href=".index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="signup.html">Signup</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                data-toggle="dropdown">Explore<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Further Actions</a></li>
                </ul></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
</div>
```

And My script reload-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = '/Motion/success.html'

    $(document).ready(function() {      
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
        var username = '';
        var password = '';                  
        var cubename = '';  
        var status = 'load';

    setInterval(function() {
                $("#buntha").load('/Motion/success.html',
                    {username:'<%=userName%>',password:'<%=Password%>',status:status})
                    .fadeIn("slow");
                }, 10000);

    });

</script>
```

and my Controller Post method-

**changed the controller to return JSON**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/success", method=RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=*/*")
public Model success(@Valid @ModelAttribute("username") String username,@Valid @ModelAttribute("password") String password,@Valid String cubename,@Valid String status, BindingResult result,Model model) {     
    log.info("Posting Data in Success With "+username+" passowrd "+password+" Cubename "+cubename+" status "+status);

    boolean found = studentService.findByLogin(username, password);
    if (found) {        
        if(cubename != null)
            updateDataBaseContent(username,cubename,status);

        StudentLogin studentLogin = new StudentLogin(); 
        studentLogin.setUserName(username);
        studentLogin.setPassword(password);
        List<Cube> cubes = cubeService.getCubes();
        model.addAttribute("name", studentLogin);
        model.addAttribute("message", cubes);       
    } 
    return model;
}
```

How can I avoid reloading all script files 
I am anyway calling only the div tag to load, but why its loading the netire page.
I am very new to Spring and Web, so it may be a silly query but I couldn't crack it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By watching your code, I suppose that the controller calls the entire `success.jsp` view resource (that contains the scripts).

```
model1.setViewName("success");
```

A good solution could be to setup your controller just as response producer, by using for instance **JSON** as *MediaType* and parsing that response through **JQuery** in order to manage **AJAX** requests/reponses.

[image: Sequence]

#### Usefull references:

- **[Building a RESTful Web Service](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)**
- **[jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)**
- **[Annotation Type ResponseBody](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html)**

Comment: I did change the return type as JSOn but still its loading the entire page with script ... above I updated the controller..but I do believe you gave the right approach , may be I'll figure out what still left in my code

Comment: You should't use Spring Model even now, 'cause their instances are used to render dynamic content inside a web resource (a page) through a Template Engine (in you case, the JSP engine). I suggest you to use a RESTful Web Service as shown here: http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/. To be clear, you have to send only a data stream, in that case a JSON file, and render its content on client-side by using JavaScript.